# Word designating something as being representative of a whole

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word similar to synecdoche, but without the literary-device meaning. It designates something as being representative of a whole. I believe I picked this up in a David Foster Wallace essay.

The word would be used, for example, to describe Kanye West as representing American egotism as a whole.

Comment: Can't have been as simple as *prime example* or *showcase*, can it?

Comment: Also _prototype, ideal, generic,_ and _normal,_ among many other terms, all depending on the **type** of "representativity" and the **type** of "whole" involved, all in context for the intended audience. The description is not really precise enough without any further boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Metonym**.

[Wikipedia describes metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonym) as:

> Metonymy ... is a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is called not by its own name but rather by the name of something associated in meaning with that thing or concept.

It goes on:

> For instance, "Hollywood" is used as a metonym for the U.S. film industry because of the fame and cultural identity of Hollywood, a district of the city of Los Angeles, California, as the historical center of film studios and film stars. The national capital is often used to represent the government of a country, such as "Westminster" for Parliament of the United Kingdom,

Also:

> Synecdoche and metalepsis are considered specific types of metonymy.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you're looking for *[epitome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epitome)*:

> a perfect example: an example that represents or expresses something very well

Answer (score 12):

[**embodiment**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embodiment) is quite close to the equivalent of **synecdoche** without the specific denotation of a literary device: someone or something that is a *perfect representative* or example of a *quality*, *idea*, etc.; the [representation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/embodiment) or expression of something in a tangible or visible form.

> Mother Theresa was the embodiment of devotion to others; she was selflessness itself.

Other words that mean the same thing: image, **incarnation**, incorporation, manifestation, personification, realization, substantiation; **quintessence**, archetype, exemplar.

Answer (score 8):

[*exemplar*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exemplar) comes to mind:

> a typical example or instance; an orignal or archetype

Answer (score 5):

Provided you're using it for some positive quality (or you are feeling cynical), you could use [Paragon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paragon).

> A person of preeminent qualities, who acts as a pattern or model of
>   some given (especially positive) quality.

Answer (score 4):

> Quintessence [- the purest or most typical instance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quintessence)

Comment: Oh, but the OP is looking for a single word!

Comment: @Reg: I've added a definition, since Daniel obviously doesn't realise we expect at least *some* kind of "supporting evidence". This word itself seems at least as good as any other posted so far.

Comment: This is a cool word but imo quintessential is the most overrused/trite word in pop culture at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Microcosm

something (such as a place or an event) that is seen as a small version of something much larger (from Merriam Webster online)

Answer (score 0):

I think "proxy" might be what you're looking for:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proxy